# is not a valid regular expression in urls.py

Tags: python, django, windows

I faced the problem, I need to add functions to the file `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P[0-9]+)/answer/$', views.answer, name='answer')
]
```

Running the server I get

`"^(?P[0-9]+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: unknown extension ?P[`

Tell me what's wrong...

Comment: You need to specify the *parameter name*, so `(?P<parameter_name>[0-9]+)`.

Comment: "Tell me what's wrong..." really like the attitude. maybe try django 2.0 urls are more beginner friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, that's indeed not a valid regex.

`?P` introduces a named group, which Django uses as a keyword argument. You need to provide the name of that group, surrounded by angle brackets. For example:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$'
```